# How to upsert into an array of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to upsert into array of subdocuments.
For example:

```js
const parent = new mongoose.Schema({
  children: [childrenSchema],
});

const childrenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});
```

First, I would want find a parent object and then upsert an array of children objects.  If the array I pass in has an id that matches then i would update the properties.  If they are new ids, or children with null ids then new children objects would be created.

Second, I would like to drop all the children and just persist the new list.  How would i do this atomically?

Comment: can you update the question with what you have tried until now..!Query!also expected output..!